# struggling with error on py2neo simple script

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

I've been trying to create a graph using py2neo / neo4j but I'm constantly hitting problems with my script. The latest one being the following...
(bare in mind that i am also new to python. sorry!)

Here is the code:

```
from py2neo import neo4j, node
graph = neo4j.GraphDatabaseService("http://localhost:7474/db/data/")
graph.clear()
i_word = graph.get_or_create_index(neo4j.Node, "i_word")
i_token = graph.get_or_create_index(neo4j.Node, "i_token")
labels = {"TOKEN"}
properties = {"name": "Ana"}
a_node = node(*labels, **properties)
c_node, = graph.create(a_node)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
... py2neo/neo4j.py", line 237 
... TypeError: Cannot cast node from (('TOKEN',), {'name':'Ana'})
```

Any ideas? many thanks for your time.
rgds, 
Pedro

Answer (score 0):

The `node` function in py2neo 1.6 does not have label support. You can only supply properties for creation and then later add labels. The alternative will be to use a Cypher expression such as:

```
CREATE n:TOKEN {name:'Ana'}
```

As a side note, bear in mind also that labels are generally be written in **TitleCase** rather than **UPPER_CASE**.